# Quartiles and normal distribution

Tags: statistics

If $Q_1, Q_2, Q_3$ are the quartiles of a set of data and $$Q_3 - Q_2 = Q_2 - Q_1$$does that indicate a normal distribution?

Answer (score 2):

It is an indication that you have a symmetrical distribution. This could be the uniform distribution, the triangle distribution or the normal distribution as you said. To check symmetry you also need further indications such as that the mean is almost equal to the median.

Comment: Could you give an example of a uniform distribution that is not a normal distribution?

Comment: @Mathperson Do not confuse "uniform" with "symmetrical". Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) for the uniform and look [here](https://www.rocscience.com/help/swedge/webhelp/swedge/Triangular_Distribution.htm) or [here](http://www.mcglamery.com/academic/ChE473K/statistics/triangdist.html) for symmetrical triangle distribution.

Comment: @Mathperson Look also [here](http://www.uic.edu/classes/bios/bios101/genes1/sld009.htm) for the bi-modal distribution, which is another example of symmetrical distribution, which satisfies your condition, but which is not normal, and (not even approximately normal, as for example the triangular distribution, which "looks like" normal)

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. For instance: the uniform distribution also has this property.